# How to make a blender addon with multiple folders?

Tags: python, blender

I want to make blender addons with Python, but using just one file gets very crowded. Is there a way that I can make it more than one file with folders and all that cool stuff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(From https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/105979/)

Organize your folder structure like this:

```
myaddon/
├── __init__.py
├── operators/
    ├── first_operator.py
```

In the `__init__.py` do this:

```
import bpy

from .operators.first_operator import FirstOperator

bl_info = {
    "name": "MyAddon",
    "description": "A demo addon",
    "author": "myname",
    "version": (1, 0, 0),
    "blender": (2, 7, 9),
    "wiki_url": "my github url here",
    "tracker_url": "my github url here/issues",
    "category": "Animation"
}

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_module(__name__)
```

In the `operators/first_operator.py` file, do this:

```
import bpy

class FirstOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_label = "First Operator"
    bl_idname = "myaddon.first_operator"
    bl_description = "A demo operator"
    
    def execute(self, context):
        print("hello world")
        
        return {"FINISHED"}
```

You'll have to install the addon to use it. You can't just run the `__init__.py` from the text editor in Blender to make it work.

---

If you're going down this path, I'd strongly recommend using Visual Studio Code with the "Blender Development" extension, it is amazing and takes away all the trouble of having to manually load/reload the extension every time you make a change.

Comment: If the answer solves your problem could you approve it? :)

Comment: i would but i do not have enough reputation. :(

Comment: whoops i did not know that i could check the check mark. :)

Comment: Over here do i replace the `__name__`with the operator name?

Comment: @Shikha The operator name is controlled by `bl_label`. This is what the buttons in the UI will show.